# What's the easiest way in Excel to calculate the number of workdays above a certain number of hours in a schedule?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm making a weekly schedule for employees in Excel. This is one that is distributed to employees, so I need to make it easy to read. Currently I have for each-employee, from left-to-right, their start and end time for Monday, then Tuesday, and so on. That's the part everyone looks at, so I don't want to mess with that part if I can help it.

To the right of it, I need to know their total number of hours for that week. Currently I have that calculated like so:

```
=((D5-C5) * 24) + ((F5-E5) * 24) + ((H5-G5) * 24) + ((J5-I5) * 24) + ((L5-K5) * 24) + ((N5-M5) * 24) + ((P5-O5) * 24)
```

Each calculation is the end time minus the start time, and that gets me a number that's close, but since Excel doesn't know about labor law, of course it doesn't subtract half an hour from each day totaling 5 or more hours. I've gotten around this so far with a manually entered column called Days w/Lunch, and then I can just subtract the value of that column * .5 from the first column for a corrected total. However, I'd like to use a function to automate that.

I've done a little bit of Googling and it seems like I should be able to use `CountIf`, `SumIf`, or `SumProduct` to do this, but I'm not sure exactly how. I've thought of having a bunch of cells for each employee for each day which checks the number of hours and counts it as a day w/lunch if it's 5 or above hours, but that seems like an ugly solution. Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Why don't you share some sample data with us,, I think you have made the job complected otherwise is like get the `Daily Worked hours` then `G. Total` for the `Week` and adjust `Lunch Time` to get `Exact Worked Hours`.

Comment: You're right, I think I worded that rather poorly, sorry about that. I didn't include a table because I wasn't sure how to do it with markdown formatting, but Kenneth was able to help me out below. Thank you, though!

Comment: Check @Johnny C I've posted solution calculates Working Days, will help you lot. ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula can be simplified into:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C5:P5,{-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1})*24
```

Which means (C5*-1 + D5*1 + E5*-1 + F5*1 + ... + O5*-1 + P5*1) * 24.

To count the number of days with over 5 hours, seems that you do not want to change the structure, I come up with a formula

```
=-SUM(D5-C5>5/24,F5-E5>5/24,H5-G5>5/24,J5-I5>5/24,L5-K5>5/24,N5-M5>5/24,P5-O5>5/24)*0.5
```

It doesn't look neat, but work as a single formula. For instance `D5-C5>5/24` returns TRUE (also interpreted as 1 by Excel) or FALSE (also interpreted as 0 by Excel). So it counts the number of days that is over 5 hours, multiplied by -0.5.

Making everything in one single formula, that would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C5:P5,{-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1})*24-SUM(D5-C5>5/24,F5-E5>5/24,H5-G5>5/24,J5-I5>5/24,L5-K5>5/24,N5-M5>5/24,P5-O5>5/24)*0.5
```

Drag this formula downwards and it can be easily applied to all workers.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was asked for! I ended up having to restructure it in a different way, but thank you for answering my question and confirming my suspicion that it was doable in one formula. I'll be able to use that syntax in the future.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest few simple methods to create TIME SHEET, which are popular & in practice also, across industries.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Data range for 1st method is `A2:E7`.
- Apply Cell Format `hh:mm` to Data Range.
- Formula in `G2`: `=(E2-B2)-(D2-C2)`.

**Note:**

- Fill Formula down & apply Format `hh:mm`.
- Another Formula you may use is in `H2`:

`=SUM(C2-B2)+(E2-D2)`

- Fill it down & apply `h" Hrs. and "m" Mins."` Format to cells.
- Formula in `G9` and `H9` to get Week Total is: `=SUM(G2:G7)` & `=SUM(H2:H7)`, apply Format `0.00 " Days"` to cell.

**Or, you may use this Formula also to Convert Total Worked hours into Days, Hours & Minutes in Cell G12.**

```
=IF(INT(SUM(G2:G7))>0,INT(SUM(G2:G7))&" days, ","")& IF(HOUR(SUM(G2:G7))>0, HOUR(SUM(G2:G7)) & " hours, ","")& IF(MINUTE(SUM(G2:G7))>0, MINUTE(SUM(G2:G7)) & " minutes ","")
```

- Data Range For **Fix Lunch Time** method is `A12:D17` and Cell Format is `hh:mm`.
- Formula in `E12`: `=D12-B12-C12`.
- Use **SUM** to get Week total shown above 
  along with Cell Format `0.00 " Days"`.
- Or you may also use the Formula, I've 
  suggested to use in cell `G12`.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*